# Neo4j Cypher "at least 2 directors and at least 5 actors"

Tags: neo4j, count, cypher

Which film has at least 2 directors and at least 5 actors? So far got this but it gives me the wrong answer. It gives too many movies and counts.

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)<-[:DIRECTED]-(d:Person) WITH m, count(a) AS numAct, count(d) AS numDir WHERE numAct >= 5 AND numDir >= 2 RETURN  m.title, numDir AS director_count, numAct AS actor_count
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the aggregation part works is that it groups by the movie node 'm'. In the part,

```
...WITH m, count(a) AS numAct, count(d) AS numDir...
```

it will collect the movies, actors and directors as separate rows, one row for **each combination of movie, actor and director** and then counts the rows. If you run,

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)<-[:DIRECTED]-(d:Person) 
RETURN m, a, d
```

you will see exactly the rows that the count aggregation will work on

To solve your problem, you will have to update the cypher, breaking up the aggregation. One way is,

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie) WITH m, count(a) AS numAct
MATCH (m)<-[:DIRECTED]-(d:Person) WITH m, numAct, count(d) as numDir
WHERE numAct >= 5 AND numDir >= 2 
RETURN  m.title, numDir AS director_count, numAct AS actor_count
```

*Updated after @Graphileon's observation*

Comment: I don't think this query returns the correct results, it returns cartesian products. on the standard movie db, it returns 3 directors and 12 actors for the Cloud Atla movie

Comment: Yes, you are right! it returns wrong results. Not because of cartesian, but the first match part was wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the shortest way is

```
MATCH (m:Movie)
WHERE size([(m)<-[:DIRECTED]-(p:Person) | p]) >= 2
      AND size([(m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(p:Person) | p]) >= 5
RETURN m
```